# Wie verbreitet ist »Wunderwuzzi«

Tags: word-usage

Meine Landsleute haben am 15. Oktober bei der österreichischen Nationalratswahl jene Partei auf Platz 1 gewählt, die derzeit von dem erst 31-jährigen Außenminister Sebastian Kurz angeführt wird. Sebastian Kurz wird, wenn er tatsächlich Kanzler werden sollte (was äußerst wahrscheinlich ist) der jüngste Regierungschef der Welt sein. In den vergangenen Jahren fiel er bereits durch seinen Tatendrang und viele unkonventionelle Ideen auf.

Mancherorts erzählt man sich sogar, er könne Blinde sehend machen und über Wasser gehen. So jemanden, dem man einfach alles zutraut (ob zurecht oder nicht sei dahingestellt), nennt man in Österreich einen »Wunderwuzzi«.

Ein *Wuzzi* ist eigentlich ein flinker kleiner Wicht. Viele männliche Hunde, vor allen kleinerer Rassen, tragen in Österreich den Namen *Wuzzi*. Wenn dann so ein kleiner Wuzzi auch noch Wunder wirken kann (oder wenn man es ihm zumindest zutraut), dann ist das eben ein *Wunderwuzzi*. Diese Bezeichnung ist halb bewundernd, aber auch halb ironisch gemeint. Ich kenne niemanden, auf den diese Bezeichnung besser passt, als auf den »Basti«, wie er sich auch gerne nennen lässt.

Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wunderwuzzi) kennzeichnet das Wort *Wunderwuzzi* als »österreichisch umgangssprachlich«, Wiktionary hat dazu gar keinen Eintrag, und die Google-Suche nach »DWDS Wunderwuzzi« spuckt als ersten Treffer »DWDS – Tausendsassa« aus, was einigermaßen als Synonym durchgeht. (Ein Wunderwuzzi ist klein oder jugendlich, was der Tausendsassa nicht unbedingt sein muss.)

Ich frage mich nun, ob das Wort *Wunderwuzzi* auch in Deutschland bekannt ist. Ich stelle diese Frage, weil der britische Sender BBC in seiner Berichterstattung über die österreichische Nationalratswahl zu meiner Überraschung sehr wohl dieses Wort verwendet: [Hier](https://www.bbc.com/pidgin/world-41575723) und [hier](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-41627586).

Sogar die Süddeutsche Zeitung titelte, allerdings schon vor dreieinhalb Jahren: »[Wunderwuzzi auf der Weltbühne](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/politik/oesterreichs-aussenminister-kurz-wunderwuzzi-auf-der-weltbuehne-1.1864906)«.

Comment: Ist in Mitteldeutschland nicht bekannt. Klingt ziemlich süddeutsch.

Comment: Ich kannte den Begriff vor dem rasanten Aufstieg von Herrn Kurz auch nicht - Er ist aber lautmalerisch und treffend genug, dass man auch ohne Wörterbuch ungefähr weiß, was gemeint ist.  Die BBC zitiert ja nur, der "Wunderwuzzi" dürfte für einen durchschnittlichen britischen Leser jetzt auch nicht fremder sein als das (im eher) verbreitete deutsche "Tausendsassa"

Comment: Trotz lebenslangen Aufenthalts in Süddeutschland ist mir das Wort noch nie begegnet, so weit also kein Widerspruch zum Duden.

Comment: Habe das Wort noch nie zuvor gehört oder gelesen, hört sich für mich nach "Kindersprache" an.

Comment: Das Wort ist in einem einschlägigen Forum, das sich mit übertriebenen Fahrzeugen beschäftigt, ein gängiger Begriff. Das Forum von Nutzern aus dem gesamten deutschsprachigen Raum (bis Norddeutschland) besucht.

Comment: @tofro: So rasant ist der Aufstieg des Herrn Kurz gar nicht. Er ist schon seit 2011, also seit sechs Jahren, Mitglied der Bundesregierung (damals war er 25), und damit ist er unter den ÖVP-Regierungsmitgliedern bereits das am längsten amtierende Regierungsmitglied. Auch die meisten Regierungsmitglieder des Koalitionspartners SPÖ sind erst nach Sebastian Kurz in die Regierung gekommen. Es gibt nur ein einziges Regierungsmitglied, das länger als Kurz zur Regierung gehört, das ist der SPÖ-Mister Alois Stöger (er ist seit 9 Jahren in der Regierung).

Comment: Vielleicht auch interessant: https://trends.google.de/trends/explore?q=wunderwuzzi

Comment: Wuzzerl als Bezeichnung für einen kleinen Hund habe ich mal gehört, in einem alten Film aus Österreich, ausgestrahlt im deutschen Fernsehen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das Wort ist laut Duden österreichisch umgangssprachlich. In Deutschland wird *Wuzzi* und in Kombination mit Zusammensetzungen gar nicht verwendet, kann aber leicht aus dem Kontext erschlossen werden, was es bedeuten soll. Es ähnelt *Fuzzi*, *wuseln*, in gewisser Weise auch dem südlich verwendeten *Superburschi* und wird in Kombination mit *Wunder* zur Alliteration. Momentan wird es nur speziell in Verbindung mit dem in der Frage genannten politischen Ereignis als populäres Medienschlagwort verwendet.